# matlab scrollpanel addNewLocationCallback: callback function with additional arguments

Tags: matlab, callback

I am displaying large images in matlab using overviewpanel.
I would like image contrast to adjust to the range of values in the visible portion of my image.

I wrote a function `adjcontrast(hIm, SPapi)` which takes the image handle and the scroll panel api as arguments and does this adjustment. I would like this function to be called whenever location or magnification of the scrollpanel changes.

with `SPapi.addNewLocationCallback(@adjcontrast)`  , `adjcontrast(loc)` is called whenever the location changes in my scrollpanel. How can I get it to pass the two additional arguments `hIm` and `SPapi`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on Lucius answer: `SPapi.addNewLocationCallback(@(~)adjcontrast(hIm, SPapi))` did the job.

Comment: well done! if you could just give a short explanation why you did it this way,m I definetly give you a +1 :)

Comment: What is the `@(~)`, can it be reduced to `@()` ?

Comment: Not so clear to me either how it works, but this is my understanding: `@(~)adjcontrast(hIm,SPapi)` is the handle of a function taking a single input argument, so it can be called as `adjcontrast(loc)`. After the first `SPapi.addNewLocationCallback` call, `hIm` and `SPapi` values do not need to be updated anymore, and i believe they are not.

Comment: @(~) is the handle to an anonymous function that ignores the first argument. with @() i would have got a too many input arguments exception on  `adjcontrast(loc)`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if this helps in your case, but this is the way you do this with a usual GUI-component:

You have to put it within curly braces, like this:

```
set(hb,'Callback',{@pushbutton_callback,myvar,'--m'})
```

for reference:

[writing-code-for-callbacks](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/creating_guis/writing-code-for-callbacks.html)

[function-handle-callbacks--Defining Callbacks as a Cell Array of Strings — Special Case](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/creating_plots/function-handle-callbacks.html#f7-37640)

Comment: SPapi.addNewLocationCallback({@adjcontrast, hIm, SPapi}) does not work in this particular case

Comment: what eror-message do you get?

Comment: subscript indices must either be real positive or logical, in imscrollpanel/sendNewLocation()